# Влияет ли имя таблицы, как параметр хранимой процедуры, на производительность?

Tags: mysql, sql

Хочу реализовать хранимую процедуру, которая будет принимать название таблицы, колонки и значение для повышения производительности, т.к. очень часто выполняется это событие (вставка 1-го значения в таблицу (результат нормализации)). Т.е. это событие будет часто выполняться когда проект только запустится и БД будет пустой, но всё же не хочется терять производительность сервера на синтаксический анализ запроса. Но вот есть сомнение, что наличие названия таблицы как параметра хранимой процедуры, сможет повысить производительность. Ведь по-прежнему серверу надо будет проводить анализ запроса на наличие запрашиваемой таблицы.

Comment: Не влияет. Название таблицы - литерал, который первым делом преобразуется во внутренний индекс объекта.

Comment: @Akina спасибо)